# Trying to program code to Exit application upon ESC in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am learning more C# programming and have developed an application using Ogre. However the only method I have of exiting the application when running it is, ALT+F4.

I have put in the code a method to Exit with keyPress ESC. However, Visual C# Express is throwing error, and not letting me use ProcessCmdKey. :\

Help?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref LogMessageLevel msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape) this.Close();
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: You need this wrapped inside a `class` that inherits from `Form`, it can't be standalone code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More standard way is adding close button to the form then set this button as the Form Cancel button.

For more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx

By setting it as Cancel button, it will be triggered automatically upon pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("esc pressed!");
        this.Close();
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```